# How to remove repetitive characters from std::string

Tags: c++, stl

I have got a `std::string` like this:

```
std::string fileName;
```

where `fileName` is like `/tmp/fs////js//config.js`
It is coming from somewhere and I need to store it. But when I store it, I need to remove extra '/' chars from the path, basically need only one separator between directory names and file names.

I can remove these by iterating over the string one char at a time and comparing with the next char, but its not very efficient.

Can anyone suggest some efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why do you think it's not efficient? It's O(n), and you can't get any more efficient for that problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient' (fast, elegant or memory)? Can you provide your attempt as part of the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to find anything more efficient than that - think about it - you need to remove consecutive duplicated characters - the imnplication is that, even in the best case, you're going to have to look at every character at least once.

Comment: Thanks, I will then stick to my original solution.

Comment: This is not 100% true. The actual naïve algorithm is not O(N), but O(N^2) (each character removal is a linear operation in itself, as it requires all elements from that position to the end of the string to be *moved*) Then again, in most cases and unless the strings are big with a big number of duplicates, it might still be more efficient than a purely linear algorithm that requires copying.

Comment: @David the naive algorithm is what you are likely to do if you use a home-made loop calling erase() multiple times. remove_if however will remain O(N). Meyers was totally correct in advocating its use.

Comment: O(N) in time + O(N) in memory, not O(N^2) unless you want to do it in-place

Answer (score 8):

Removing duplicate adjacent elements is a job for `std::unique`. You need to provide your own predicate in this case but it's O(n) and dead simple.

```
struct both_slashes {
    bool operator()(char a, char b) const {
        return a == '/' && b == '/';
    }
};

std::string path("/tmp/fs////js//config.js");

path.erase(std::unique(path.begin(), path.end(), both_slashes()), path.end());
```

Comment: probably better than remove_if because the predicate is tidier.

Comment: +1 This makes very efficient use of the standard library and should be the accepted answer, IMHO.

Comment: I don't know why you edited your original solution though, where both_slashes was a plain function.

Comment: @CashCow: I don't recall why I revisited this answer. The edit does reflect how I would write the code this year rather than 3 years ago. Actually, I'd probably just use a lambda unless I needed the functor somewhere else.

Comment: yeah I'd probably use a lambda now too.

Answer (score 3):

I think `std::unique` will work even though your string is not sorted because all it removes is consecutive duplicates.

Of course it won't know that `/` is a special character here and you may find file-names that contain double-letters also getting modified unexpectedly to single-leter, posibly anoyingly.

It is also O(N) but you can't avoid that.

One algorithm that will work well is std::remove_if because you can put in your own "functor" which can keep state so it will know what the last character was.

```
struct slash_pred
{
  char last_char;

  slash_pred()
   : last_char( '\0' ) // or whatever as long as it's not '/'
  {
  }

  bool operator()(char ch)
  {
      bool remove = (ch == '/') && (last_char == '/');
      last_char = ch;
  }
};

path.erase( std::remove_if( path.begin(), path.end(), 
      slash_pred() ), path.end() );
```

O(N) but should work.

For the dissenters who think `remove_if` might be O(N^2) it might be implemented like this:

```
template< typename ForwardIterator, typename Pred >
ForwardIterator remove_if( ForwardIterator read, ForwardIterator end, Pred pred )
{
   ForwardIterator write = read; // outside the loop as we return it
   for( ; read!=end; ++read )
   {
      if( !pred( *read ) )
      {
         if( write != read ) // avoid self-assign
         {
            *write = *read;
         }
         ++write;
      }
   }
   return write;
}
```

Comment: Yea, if he only wants to remove consecutive slashes, then this would be a silly idea.

Comment: @David you are wrong about remove_if. I will implement it to show you it is O(N).

Comment: @CashCow That doesn't work in any C++ library because the "pred" object might be copied inside the "remove_if" function. You should instantiate a "slash_pred" object and pass it to "remove_if" using "std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&slash_pred::operator()), &pred)".

Comment: @FernandoSilveira the pred may be copied but only once, not on each iteration therefore it will hold its state. However this is still as good as unique with custom predicate (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

O(n) in time + O(n) in mem

```
void clean_path(std::string& path) {
    std::string new_path;
    char sep = '/';
    for (auto i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i) {
        if (path[i] == sep && !new_path.empty() && new_path.back() == sep)
            continue;
        new_path.push_back(path[i]);
    }
    path = new_path;
}
```